# Jmeter - Websocket plugin - unable to find solution to constantly read incoming messages

Tags: websocket, parallel-processing, jmeter, listener, jmeter-plugins

Good afternoon.

I have implemented websockets in my project using the plugin "WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch" in Jmeter.
So far the requirements were simply to send and receive some payload, or simply send and forget.

However I got a new requirement where the server will constantly send back websocket message to client at every 5 second interval.

Ex: I send ABC , XYZ, ABD at every 3 second interval and I need to read XYC, YTZ at every 5 second interval both should happen simultaneously

I'm unable to use Parallel Controller as each item within the controller is a separate thread and thus I will loose web socket connection for the second one.

Is there any way I can achieve this using some listeners or something.

Thanks for your response in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/):

> **Fragmentation**
>
> WebSocket messages may be fragmented into several frames. In such cases the first frame is an ordinary text or binary frame, but it will have the `final` bit cleared. The succeeding frames will be continuation frames (whether they are text or binary is inferred by the first frame) and the last continuation frame will have the `final` bit set. The plugin supports continuation frames, but as the plugin is frame-oriented, you'll have to read them yourself. In cases where the number of fragments is known beforehand, this is as easy as adding an extra WebSocketReadSampler for each continuation frame you expect. If the number of continuation frames is not known, you need to create a loop to read all the continuation frames. For this purpose, the plugin provides a new JMeter variable called `websocket.last_frame_final` that indicates whether the last frame read was final. This enables you to write a simple loop with a standard JMeter While Controller; use the expression `${__javaScript(! ${websocket.last_frame_final},)}` as condition. With a JMeter If Controller, the condition can be simplified to ! ${websocket.last_frame_final} because that controller automatically interprets the condition as JavaScript. See the sample [Read continuation frames.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Read%20continuation%20frames.jmx) test plan for examples of using the While or the If controller to read continuation frames.
>
> If you are unsure whether continuation frames are sent by your server or how much, switch on [debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging): samplers reading a frame will log whether the received frame is a "normal" single frame, a non-final frame (i.e. 1st fragment), a continuation frame or a final continuation frame (last fragment).

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T, this is good information! However, my messages are continuous and I have no problem reading them. The complexity is I need to send some message to websocket constantly and keep listening for incoming message without using parallel thread!
There are no relation to what I send and what I receive!
Ex: I send ABC , XYZ, ABD at every 3 second interval and I need to read XYC, YTZ at every 5 second interval both should happen simultaneously